# How to use T parameter for evaluating its type c#

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, typeof

I want to evaluate a T parameter to perform a common behavior.

I was trying to do call this method from differents buttons

```
private void Execute<T>(string strValue)
{
     //Do operations
     this.SaveObject<T>();
}
```

Button1

```
this.Execute<Employee>("somevalue1");
```

Button2

```
this.Execute<Supplier>("somevalue2");
```

but then the problem is when I want to define the SaveObject method at that point how can I evaluate the T. I tried this but I tells me the T is a parameter and I'm using it as a variable.

```
private void SaveObject<T>()
{
    //Here the problem
    if(T is Employee)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    if(T is Supplier)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

I want to know what kind of type is and then do my specific operations. All the objects inherit EntityObject

**------EDIT------**

At the moment of the question, the only thing that I needed to fix my problem was the "answer comment" from Silvermind. (typeof(T)) Then I took the approach from many of you to improve the architecture.

If Silvermind would have aswered my question as answer more than a comment, that would have been my accepted answer.

Anyway, thanks to all of you guys.

Comment: Sounds like T is no longer generic then. Give them both a common `ISaveableObject` interface, and constrain the generic on that.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using generics for this. The point of generics is that you don't care about the type, save a couple constraints. If you had some interface that had a Category field, you might get a little farther, but passing something as 'i dont care' and then immediately proving you care is pointless.

Comment: `if (typeof(T) == typeof(Employee)))`

Comment: Your design is totally wrong.

Comment: @Silvermind and subclasses?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would upvote that comment a thousand times. I've had to unravel mistakes like that ingrained into projects, it's not fun.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `if (typeof(Employee).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` edit: I know it was a retorical question and this is how to do it, but I agree with asawyer.

Comment: T is a type, `is` releveant only to objects

Comment: You're placing custom type-specific logic in the generic implementation, where it does not belong. You should implement each of those in the type-specific subclass of this base generic class (such as `EmployeeService` and `SupplierService` or the like).

Comment: @Silvermind Yes, use reflection in what should be a simple compile time method resolution. (Assuming the next step would be to invoke a type specific method)

Comment: @HighCore that's exactly what I'm gonna do in the section DO SOMETHING. In fact, I have already all my business rules as you wrote EmployeeService and SupplierService. My example was for a speficic case when I'm using 1 page with two repeaters that have almost the same  operation. In order to simplify the repeated code I started to do some generic methods and then evaluate the type to call the respective Service.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree that it is not the appropriate approach and I wouldn't dare adding it as an answer :).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If I'm wrong, can you explain us how to change the approach, please?

Comment: @MaximusDecimus [Someone already did that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228797/how-to-use-t-parameter-for-evaluating-its-type-c-sharp#comment30167839_20228797), so he didn't need to.

Comment: I don't know the right solution because you did not present the problem. Instead you presented the solution. But if type is code is invariably wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HighCore is correct, if you want to implement this functionality, your best choice would be to create an abstract base class with the supported virtual methods and then override them in type-specific classes which inherit from the abstract base class. Something similar to:

```
public abstract class BaseManager<T> where T : class {
    public virtual void SaveObject() {
        // Some common save logic if it can be done
    }
}

public class EmployeeManager : BaseManager<Employee> {
    public override void SaveObject() 
    {
        // Your save logic
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: That would perhaps be the best choice *if one has control over the types in question*.  Unfortunately, that isn't possible, and so one may have to make run-time decisions based upon the type.

Comment: If the solution is set up properly with IoC and an abstract property with the type exists in the BaseManager, then you can inject IEnumerable<IManager> into the constructor and then SingleOrDefault the correct concrete manager based on type...if one doesn't have control over the types being used ahead of time. (This solution assume that an IManager or other interface exists that the container can resolve against.)

Comment: `HighCore is correct` - Thanks =). This is why I don't get too much rep lately. I keep commenting these questions and leaving it up for other people to create answers. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use `typeof(T)` from within your generic method.

**EDIT**

To give clarification (for those people who love downvoting :-) ), you can then use this information in your method as follows:

```
    private void SaveObject<T>()
    {
        //Here the problem
        if (typeof(Employee).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
```

Apologies for not being as explicit before.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I really love downvoting these kind of non-answers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - fair enough - thanks for prompting me to improve my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you find yourself writing generic code where you are saying

```
if (typeof(T)==typeof(SomeType))
```

Most likely there is some error in your logic. You might want to do method overloading. If you only know how to handle `SomeType` and `SomeOtherType` then why not have a `Save(SomeType)`, `Save(SomeOtherType)`.

If you can maybe you can make your types conform to an Interface or have a base class. That way you can redefine it like so and move the effort of saving the item on itself and keep all the prep and post logic in the handler thread::

```
void Save<T>(T item) where T:ICanSave
{
       //prep code here
      item.Save()
       //finalize code here
}
```

Of course, perhaps your object doesn't need to know how to save itself, so you may want to move the implementation into a provider so that there is a `SaveProvider<T>`, and so any arbitrary item can be saved provided somebody sends you a provider...

```
void Save<T>(T item,SaveProvider<T> provider){
       //prep code here
      provider.Save(item)
      //finalize code here
}
```

Of course you can probably default this stuff too.

Comment: If a method is called with arguments of a generic type, method and overloads are only considered if they would be satisfied by the generic type's *constraints*.  If a generic type's constraints don't satisfy an overload, the overload will not be used with any generic type--even types which would satisfy their requirements.

Comment: I think you wouldn't really need a generic type constraint for the first when you only call a `Save` method on the interface. I mean I would just say: `void Save(ICanSave item) { item.Save(); }`.

Comment: This isn't so much an "error in logic" as an "error in design".

Comment: @SilverMind,That's true about the `ICanSave`, but maybe Save adds it to a `List<T>`, or maybe it news up `ICanSave`, we don't know what else happens in the prep and finalizing steps.
@simon whitehead, you are completely correct. Sorry, I wrote this quickly.